# How to mock socket.io-client using jest/react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am building a chat app and would like to write integration tests using `react-testing-library` and can not figure out how to mock `socket.io-client`'s `socket.on`, `socket.emit`, etc.

I tried follow this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/testing-socket-io-client-app-using-jest-and-react-testing-library-9cae93c070a3/) and tried using [mock-socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-socket.io) and [socket.io-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-mock) all with no luck.

This is the component I am trying to test:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import 'dotenv/config';
import ChatInput from './ChatInput';
import Messages from './Messages';

function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const port = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT;
  const socket = io(`http://localhost:${port}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket
      .emit('app:load', messageData => {
        setMessages(messages => [...messages, ...messageData]);
      })
      .on('message:new', newMessage => {
        setMessages(messages => [...messages, newMessage]);
      });
  }, []);

  const postMessage = input => {
    socket.emit('message:post', input);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Messages messages={messages} />
      <ChatInput postMessage={postMessage} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a late answer but maybe useful for others:

to mock `socket.io-client` library I used jest mock function and used a third party library `socket.io-mock` https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-mock

You need to modify your connection function as follows in order to work with mocked socket:

```
const url= process.env.NODE_ENV==='test'?'':`http://localhost:${port}`;
const socket = io(url);
```

Implementation:

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import MockedSocket from 'socket.io-mock';

jest.mock('socket.io-client');

describe('Testing connection', () => {
  let socket;

  beforeEach(() => {
    socket = new MockedSocket();
    socketIOClient.mockReturnValue(socket);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should dispatch connect event', () => {
    /*socket should connect in App and 
    Note that the url should be dummy string 
    for test environment e.g.(const socket = io('', options);)*/
    const wrapper = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );

    expect(socketIOClient.connect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should emit message:new', done  => {
    const wrapper = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
    ...
    socket.on('message:new', (data)=>{
        expect(data).toEqual(['message1', 'message2']);
        done();
    });

    socket.socketClient.emit('message:new', ['message1', 'message2']);
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: tried to follow this, got into "_socket2.default.mockReturnValue is not a function" error from jest. seems like the jest.mock('socket.io-client') isn't always working.

maybe version issues?

Comment: And how can you mock the socket server in this setup?

Comment: it's not working for me.`    socketIOClient.mockReturnValue(socket);
` is throwing me error