# how to mock soket.io with jest npm in javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, socket.io, jestjs, chat

I am working on a project chat app in java script using socket.io back end only, And I want to write unit test using jest ,npm . And I got trouble on 
1.  how to mock socket.io with jest 
2.  how to test console.log results

```
console.log = jest.fn();


test ('check chat status', () => {
  expect(console.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
  socket.on('connect');
  expect(console.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
  expect(console.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('Chat started\n');
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

the code I want to test is the following , app.js and chat.js

```
'use strict';

const io = require('socket.io')(3000);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('username', (data) => {
    socket.username = data.username;
    console.log(`${socket.username} joined the chat!`);

    socket.broadcast.emit('new user', socket.username);
  });

  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', {user: socket.username, message: data});
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`User left the chat`);
  });
});


chat.js 
'use strict';

const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

let username;

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log(`Chat started\n`);

  rl.question('What is your name? ', (answer) => {
    username = answer;
    socket.emit('username', {username: username});
  });
});

rl.on('line', (message) => {
  socket.emit('message', message);
});

socket.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log(`${data.user}: ${data.message}`);
});

socket.on('new user', (data) => {
  console.log(`${data} joined the chat\n`);
});

But more features will be added like authontication, attchement, private chat ...
```

this file is sent to be checked

Comment: Please provide the code you want to test

Comment: Have you tried [socket.io-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-mock), I have not used it, but may help. Otherwise, take a look at this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/testing-socket-io-client-app-using-jest-and-react-testing-library-9cae93c070a3/)

Comment: Maybe this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61501927/1548301